# Meager, Nonmeager, and Comeager

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

A set is meager if it is countable union of nowhere dense sets and otherwise it is nonmeager. A set is comeager if it is complement of meager set.  I have two problems. Let $X$ be a topological space.

1. With this definition, is it true that any set $A \subseteq X$ is meager or nonmeager?
2. I can not find $A \subseteq X$ which is not meager and not comeager. Can you help me to find this set? Thank you.

Comment: oh ya, I was wrong. thank you for your suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. excluded middle!
2. For instance $X=\Bbb R$ and $A=\{x:x>0\}$.

Comment: 1. So, there is a set which not meager and not nonmeager?

Comment: @MaurtenErik Is there a set which is empty and non-empty? non-meagre is just **not** meagre (basic linguistics too). So a set is one or the other and never neither or both.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you Sir